# How can I pull the collection view to occupy the entire screen when it initially occupies bottom half of the screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a view shown in the screenshot. In this view I have two collection views, the one at the top **Your top picks** scrolls horizontally and other at the bottom scrolls vertically.

[image]

Now I want the bottom collectionView to occupy large portion of my scree when it is being touched / Dragged as there can be 100's of cells in that.

I tried looking at few other questions of stack overflow and or library But most of them only deal with one collection view and other views at the top in which case I can just use the entire view as a header view for CollectionView and fix it. But with 2 collectionViews I am in bit of confusion of how to achieve this.

As of right now the collectionView is limited to stay at the bottom as seen in the screenshot below. I want it to occupy full screen just below the Navigation bar while it is being interacted, so that use can have much more space to scroll with.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using auto layout it’s actually quite simple to achieve, you have to override the scrollviewDidScroll method and get the contentOffset y value if it’s negative you can adjust the top constraints constant of your collection view to animate along with the scroll of the user.

If your not using autolayout your approach should be the same but you’ll need to change the origin.y value of the collection view.

I hope this gets you going in the right direction

Comment: Thank you, I will try to work using this approach and see where it goes.

Comment: Please do report back if u need any further assistance.